# Does WebClient.UploadValuesTaskAsync run its task on a separate thread if already in a task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, webclient

I am running a task in C# to make a web request. The method itself is inside of a task that then calls `webclient.UploadValuesTaskAsync` but am unsure if I should use this or just the regular `UploadValues` since the whole method is already inside of a task.

Will this create another task on another thread or would it simply run an async method on the same thread.

for example

```cs
Task.Run(async () => {
    using(WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
        byte[] = response = await wc.UploadValuesTaskAsync(uri);
    }
})
```

Or would this be more appropriate

```cs
Task.Run(() => {
    using(WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
        byte[] = response = wc.UploadValues(uri);
    }
})
```

Comment: tasks and threads are very different concepts... the default here would be: use the `await` version, so you don't block a pool thread while IO is happening

Comment: For starters, *don't* use WebClient. That class is obsolete, fully replaced by HttpClient. The two snippets are completely different though. The first is truly asynchronous, and *won't* use or block any thread while waiting for a response over the network. The second will run the code on a threadpool thread and block it while waiting for a response. This is *bad*, because that thread won't be available to serve another request

Comment: @MarcGravell From the Microsoft documentation TPL run the work of a task on separate threads or threads on other processors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos From what I have searched online is that webclient had much quicker requests than httpclient.

Comment: @mjwrazor this isn't TPL; it is async; again - completely different concept; kinda related, but: threads and tasks are *not the same thing*

Comment: @MarcGravell I am confused, after taking a course on TPL using tasks and instructions on how tasks are a way to build multithreaded programs with C# you tell me no this is all wrong. Can you show an example of a TPL httpclient version of a request that is multithreaded?

Comment: @mjwrazor you're missing the point; HTTP is - by nature - an out-of-process IO operation; you don't *want* to jam a thread for that, you want to use a different infrastructure, that allows work to be put down and picked back up *when information is available*, and that infrastructure is: `async`/`await`. Multi-threading doesn't help you very much if you just block a *different* thread. The idea is to *not block threads at all*.

Comment: @mjwrazor to be more explicit: a *task* is just a notional operation that may complete in the future; tasks *might* be CPU-based things such as multi-threading and parallelism, but by far the most common (now) use of tasks is for IO operations - where you explicitly *don't* want a thread involved (yet). It is perhaps confusing that the same metaphor (`Task`) can represent both scenarios, but: that's what it is.

Comment: There are [two types](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) of tasks: "delegate tasks" and "promise-style tasks". A delegate task runs an action or function, and completes when the action or function is complete, so it consumes a thread while running. A promise-style task is not associated with anything intrinsically, and completes when it receives an external signal that is should complete. A promise-style task is never in the `Running` state. It transitions directly from `WaitingForActivation` to completed. So it does not consume any thread by itself.